# Re-Installing Boot2Docker fails due to apparent VirtualBox running - how to shut them down?

Tags: macos, docker, virtualbox, boot2docker

I am trying to re-install boot2docker from

https://github.com/boot2docker/osx-installer/releases/tag/v1.7.0

The installation fails with the following error reported:

> The installer has detected that VirtualBox is still running. Please shutdown all running VirtualBox machines and exit VirtualBox then restart the installation.

How can I exit VirtualBox?

Comment: It looks like you're on OS X - you can use the _VirtualBox_ application to show all running VMs. Open _Spotlight_ and type _VirtualBox_, and the app should show up.

Answer (score 5):

Open VirtualBox, it will give you a list of all the VirtualBox VMs you have. You can then easily see which of them are running, and stop them by powering them off.

Answer (score 2):

If boot2docker is still available you should be able to do "boot2docker poweroff" to shutoff the VM behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had some cases where Virtualbox did not show my boot2docker VM as runnning, even though it was. If thats the case, open up your task manager, find the process VBoxHeadless, and kill it.

Comment: No such process to be seen

Answer (score 0):

This is because all the running VMs were not shutdown before uninstalling. Run VBoxManage command to list all running VMs

```
VBoxManage list runningvms
```

Then run savestate command to stop the vm

```
VBoxManage controlvm <name of vm> savestate
```

Now run the installation again.